# Inject custom properties folder in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, configuration, yaml

In my Spring Boot Application, i would like to externalise my ad-hoc configurations inside a folder. The folder is : src/main/etc/config/advanced/information-properties.yml.

Of course i have and use application.yml file in resource folder.

Using maven-resources-plugin, i'm copying this :

```
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-config</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/config</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/etc/config/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

So, I'm trying to refer to them/it using this property file:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "information")
@PropertySource(value = "file:config/advanced/information-properties.yml", ignoreResourceNotFound = true, factory = YamlPropertyLoaderFactory.class)
public class InformationPropertiesConfiguration {
    private ApplicationConfig application;

    @Data
    public class ApplicationConfig{
        private String applicationConfigPath;
    }
}
```

But when i start the application my factory doesn't find the .yml file.

```
2023-08-05 12:45:16.341  INFO 18708 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassParser         : Properties location [file:config/advanced/information-properties.yml] not resolvable: config\advanced\information-properties.yml (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato)"
```

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

EDIT
Compiling the project:
[image: Compiling the project]

[image: Unpacking the Jar]

I'm trying to understand now if i should in some ways put the folder inside the it. i think in this case it should be the outputDirectory the problem. am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**file** or FileSystemResource is not connected to ApplicationSystemResource, that basically means that you have to put absolute path to it.

You if you want relative path - you have to use either **classpath:** or none.

[image]

If you can`t find what is relative location of your file:
build your service, find the jar, unarchive the jar, find your file in the path - thats your relative path in the classpath. **If there is no file** - that means that you have a problem in copying file to jar.
Example photo of my service)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've tried with both scenarios but it doesn't work either :(

Comment: @datta900 I added an example of how to resolve the relative path of file. 
Unfortunately, i cant tell that your maven-resource plugin is fine, so you have to check it by yourself)

Comment: Got your point, i've edited the answer

Comment: SOLUTION: I've insert web-assembly-plugin, to copy the etc folder inside the jar, about the table proposed by @Vadim Yemelyanov it was part of the solution. Inside the ProprtiesConfiguration i've written classpath:/etc/... and now can find the file. PS: The example i was following loads a file .sh that copies inside a config_folder and then inside the project with all the configuration it needs (for all modules) this is why it's using file: and not classpath. Thanks for the help